# ROC Specific Time for some currencies

Tags: pine-script, var

I am here asking for help because I have little experience with pine .... I need to calculate the ROC (Rate of Change) for some currencies, but whose time is considered to be a specific time (20:25 UTC) .. the logic would be to accumulate the values of the currencies USDZAR, USDMXN, USDTRY at this specific moment and from this moment on, calculate the ROC, every day,

Answer (score 0):

This may help get you started:

```
//@version=4
study("")
f_rocFromSymbol(_sym) =>
    float r = roc(close, 1)
    bool inTime = not na(time(timeframe.period, "2025-0000:1234567"))
    security(_sym, timeframe.period, inTime ? r : na)

plot(f_rocFromSymbol("FX:USDZAR"), "FX:USDZAR", color.orange, 6, style = plot.style_linebr)
plot(f_rocFromSymbol(syminfo.tickerid), style = plot.style_linebr)
```

[image]